Best Pratices when use FileSystem (ex, existsSync and exists) in flutter
About Flutter file system documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/FileSystemEntity-class.html
There are almost two versions of any function: synchronous and asynchronous.
What are the best practices for both versions?
Should I use the unsync version in my Flutter App for a better user experience? (ex, await file.exists())
When should I use synchronized versions? (ex, file.existsSync())

my understanding is the sync ones are better unless you're doing them in a tight sync loop enough that you might start skipping frames.  try it and see. :)

A single file.fooSync() call will be faster than a single await file.foo() call.  The synchronous call is doesn't have the extra overhead.  However, if you're doing multiple asynchronous operations on a file close enough together, they're likely to get batched together and will end up being more performant.

Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36269.
